# Удаление элементов массива

Tags: javascript

Как удалить из массива с 4-го элемента по самый конец все элементы так, что бы при обращении к удаленным элементам выводилось значение undefined

Comment: например `.length = 4`

Comment: Спасибо большое! В Инете не нашел инфы на этот счет